# JSONSchema Foreign Key Check

Tags: jsonschema

How does one implement a foreign key check in JSONSchema? I can see how to implement a check on keys. Do you have to ref another document and handle it that way?

Comment: Please define "foreign key".

Comment: First JSON doc has a field customerid which has to be a customerID found in 2nd JSON doc

Comment: If you are talking about JSON values (not schemas) then there is no concept of data relations between documents defined by JSON schema, and the check is impossible to implement with means of JSON schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking of JSON Schema being used in a database, like mongodb (which supports JSON Schema validation).

JSON Schema is only designed to validate indivudal "things".

It sounds like you want referencial integrity checks, in whcih case you need to look at the databases documentation for how to do this. You cannot do it with JSON Schema